# How to keep leading zeros in excel

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

We have an output and stored in excel xls file.

The content of the file is html with table grid(`<tr>,<td>`).

The value with leading zero(like 070008) will lose leading 0 when open in excel.

How to keep the leading zeros for this case?  Does there have way to set the excel not to remove leading zeros, like set the excel cell format to be text before opening?

Ps:

1. I can not change the content of the excel file to add "`'`".
2. Format the cell in excel is not possible as when open the xls file, the content already removing the leading zero.
3. We prefer to the way of setting excel(if exists) as this excel file is offered to final customer, who may just want to open the excel file with right value.
4. Data ► Get External Data ► From Text & File ► Open ► Text Files can not work as it will show the html code in the excel, not the content we want the page display.

BTW, we use the xsl-fo to create the html page opened in excel, which means we can define the xslt stylesheet to change the table(like cell size, cell width,cell color), but we don't know how to change the stylesheet to cover the leading zero issue(like cell css style to be mso-number-format:'\@'; ).

[Format number as text in CSV when open in both Excel and Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32022211/7472144) can not fix my issue.

Comment: If you know that values have to be 6 digits, you could add them back by using the text function `=TEXT(A1,"000000")`.

Comment: No, I can not control which value would be in the cell, even can be 001234.